# Using Like and Concat in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-like

I'm loading text files into my db and trying to do some quick matching between a table that lists names of organizations, and a table that holds the text file and potential matches to those organizations.

I load the file using `LOAD INFILE CONCURRENT` and don't have any problems with that.

The twist comes from the fact that the field I'm trying to match in the raw text table (`occupationoraffiliation`) has more than just organization names in it.  So I'm trying to use `LIKE` with wildcards to match the strings.

To match the text, I'm trying to use this query:

```
UPDATE raw_faca JOIN orgs AS o
    ON raw_faca.org_id IS NULL AND raw_faca.occupationoraffiliation LIKE CONCAT('%',o.org_name,'%')
SET raw_faca.org_id = o.org_id;
```

I've also tried without `CONCAT`:

```
UPDATE raw_faca JOIN orgs AS o
    ON raw_faca.org_id IS NULL AND raw_faca.occupationoraffiliation LIKE ('%' + o.org_name + '%')
SET raw_faca.org_id = o.org_id;
```

The `raw_faca` table has ~40,000 rows and the `orgs` table has ~ 20,000 rows.  I have indexes on all the The query has been running for a couple of hours or so -- this seems like way too long for the operation.  Is the comparison I'm trying to run just that inefficient or am I doing something spectacularly stupid here?  I was hoping to avoid going line-by-line with an external php or python script.

In response to comments below about using `Match . . . Against`, I've tried the following query as well:

```
UPDATE raw_faca JOIN orgs AS o ON raw_faca.org_id IS NULL AND MATCH(raw_faca.occupationoraffiliation) AGAINST (o.org_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
SET raw_faca.org_id = o.org_id;
```

And it's giving me this error:

```
incorrect arguments to AGAINST
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

A `LIKE` clause with a leading wild card is not going to be able to take advantage of any indexes.

Comment: In other words, @tchaymore, your query has to examine `40k * 20k = 800M` combinations which explains why it is so slow.

Comment: Got it -- I have been using external scripts, which face basically the same problem.  Any ideas on how to do matching within a field, like I'm trying to do here, in a way that would take advantage of indexes?

Comment: @tchaymore: If this is a MyISAM table, you could look into setting up a [full-text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: I have a full-text index on `occupationoraffiliation` field -- should  also put one on the two `org_id` fields?  Right now they're just indexes.

Comment: @tchaymore: Then you should be able to convert your `LIKE` into something along the lines of `...AND MATCH(raw_faca.occupationoraffiliation) AGAINST (o.org_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)...`

Comment: Thanks -- never ran across Match / Against before, but here's what I'm trying: `UPDATE raw_faca JOIN orgs AS o ON raw_faca.org_id IS NULL AND MATCH(raw_faca.occupationoraffiliation) AGAINST (o.org_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);` and it's giving me a syntax error near "" -- no explanation provided.  Any thoughts?